# FormatMessage is not always providing the correct output - Certain values being duplicated - why?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, c-strings, formatmessage

STRINGTABLE Item:

- ID: `IDS_TPL_SWAP_CONFIRMATION`
- Value: `5149`
- Caption: `Swap assignments:\n\n%1 - %2 [%3]\n%4 - %5 [%6]\n\nPlease confirm.`

Sometimes when I try this code:

```
CString strPrompt = _T("");
strPrompt.FormatMessage(IDS_TPL_SWAP_CONFIRMATION,
    m_pEntry->GetMeetingDateAsString(),
    (LPCTSTR)strExistingName,
    (LPCTSTR)strExistingDescription,
    pReplacement->GetMeetingDateAsString(),
    (LPCTSTR)getter(pReplacement),
    (LPCTSTR)strReplacementDescription);
```

I was finding on occasion that the `%1` value was being duplicated for the `%4` value, even though `pReplacement->GetMeetingDateAsString()` was actually a different date.

In the end I have changed the code like this:

```
strPrompt.LoadString(IDS_TPL_SWAP_CONFIRMATION);
strPrompt.Replace(_T("%1"), m_pEntry->GetMeetingDateAsString());
strPrompt.Replace(_T("%2"), strExistingName);
strPrompt.Replace(_T("%3"), strExistingDescription);
strPrompt.Replace(_T("%4"), pReplacement->GetMeetingDateAsString());
strPrompt.Replace(_T("%5"), getter(pReplacement));
strPrompt.Replace(_T("%6"), strReplacementDescription);
```

This works for me guaranteed. I am using the `FormatMessage` syntax because my application supports over 50languages and I could not be sure that each language would want the data in the same order.

As mentioned, all data is correct is except in some instances it would re-use the first date for the fourth item in the final output. Are there any issues I need to know about with `FormatString`?

My workaround is working fine for me in the meeting time.

Comment: Looks like `pReplacement->GetMeetingDateAsString()` and/or `m_pEntry->GetMeetingDateAsString()` are not pure functions have some side effect going on. Maybe a global or a cache issue changes the value of one another.

Comment: Or even an undefined behaviour like returning a local variable as reference from one of those functions.

Comment: @lepsch That function simply contains: `return (LPCTSTR)m_datDate.Format(VAR_DATEVALUEONLY);`. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Looks like an undefined behaviour then. I assume `m_datDate` is a `CString` as well. When you do `return (LPCTSTR)m_datDate.Format(VAR_DATEVALUEONLY);` it's creating a new copy of `CString` object locally, converting to `LPCTSTR` and when you `return` the scope is over and this temporary object is destroyed. So, when you call both on a function call the result would be the last one. But as this is an undefined behavior anything can happens

Comment: @lepsch `m_datDate` is a `COleDateTime` object and `Format` returns `CString`.

Comment: That would be the same. This returned `CString` object wouldn't exist anymore at the end of `GetMeetingDateAsString` as the scope is over and the object is destroyed. And you're returning a pointer to something that has been destroyed.

Comment: @lepsch But surely it hasn't? `pReplacement` itself and the master object it is pointing to still exists. My understanding is that returning a `CString` will return a copy. But you may be right ...

Comment: If you make `GetMeetingDateAsString` return a `CString` instead of an `LPCTSTR` it would be a copy and you're good to go. :)

Comment: @lepsch I have changed that function to return `CString` and reinstated `FormatMessage`. I do the cast to `(LPCTSTR)` on the returned value, as for the other parameters. It all seems good!

Comment: Off-topic: Why do you cast the parameters you input to `FormatMessage` to `(LPCTSTR)`? Is is needed to do it? PS: I never used `FormatMessage` but I would assume the parameters are alike the ones one would pass to other `CString` functions like `Format` or `AppendFormat`

Comment: @sergiol I do it purely for code analysis warnings that complain without the cast.

Comment: Never seen such errors for `CString` functions like `Format` or `AppendFormat`

Comment: @sergiol whenever I build with code analysis in vs2019 it always picks this up for all CString parameters to such methods.